# React UseEffect endless loop despite trying to add dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following code:

Users.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import {
    TableContainer,
    Table,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
    TableCell,
} from "@mui/material";
import { USERS_URL } from "../utils/Constants";

function Users() {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(USERS_URL, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")}
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            setUsers({responseData}); 
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))

        console.log(users);
    }, [users]);

    return(
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <TableContainer>
                <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650, maxWidth: 1024 }}>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Username</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">First Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Last Name</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

However, as the title states, this endlessly loops when re-rendering the components. How do I stop this from happening once it has called for the list of users I have?

Just for reference, I'm receiving the correct data from my server application as I would expect.

EDIT:-

I've changed the code to reflect what was suggested:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, []);
```

However, the array is now returning empty.

Comment: Remove users from the dependency array.

Comment: This happens because you added `users` to the dependency array and, in the very same hook, you change it (with `setUsers`), hence triggering the hook again... and again... and again. The only dependency indicated for your hook should be `setUsers`, which is granted to never change.

Comment: I've updated OP

Comment: When the component mounts for the first time, the `users` array is not yet populated because the effect that fetch data has not run yet. You should conditionally render the content with something like `return users.length > 0 ? your-UI-here : null`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to replace useEffect(() => {}, [users]); on:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, []);
```

Comment: Please see, OP, my array is now returning empty

Comment: @JamieRhys The `console.log` won't print the resulting data, because `setUsers` is asynchronous. Try logging it from outside the Effect

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `users` from the dependency array. This is because when the effect runs, you'll set the `users` state. And since you set the state, the component rerenders, and react checks if any effects need to run. Since `users` has changed, react will run the effect again, setting the state again, and so on.